# get a list of months that have passed upto todays date - PHP

Tags: php, date

I am building a blog archive, and I need to list out of the historical months for the years, so far example, today is the 22 August so my archive would should show,

- August
- July
- June
- May
- April
- March
- February
- January

I cannot for the life of my work out how to to output all the months of the year that we have not had yet.

Comment: Are you trying to get the months not passed? Or the months already passed?

Comment: I think the down vote might have been for not telling us what you have tried to do this so far.  I'd do it with php's date() function.  But what have *you* tried so far?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should look into PHP's [DateTime class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php).

```
<ul>
<?php
$dateTime = new DateTime();
do {
    $dateTime->modify('+1 month');
    echo '<li>' . $dateTime->format('F') . "</li>\n";
} while ($dateTime->format('m') < 12);
?>
</ul>
```

You question wasn't really clear, but according to your latest comment:

> Thanks, but this list out December January Feburary March April May June July, I need to output all previous months of THIS year including the current month

you want the exact opposite of what I have done here:

```
<ul>
<?php
$dateTime = new DateTime();
echo '<li>' . $dateTime->format('F') . "</li>\n";
$dateTime->modify('-1 month');
while ($dateTime->format('m') != 12) {
    echo '<li>' . $dateTime->format('F') . "</li>\n";
    $dateTime->modify('-1 month');
};
?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Lovely use of the shiny `DateTime` object. +1

Answer (score 3):

The php `date()` function can be used to show the current month:

You can get the current month like this:

```
echo date('n'); // Outputs 8 for August.
```

That also means you can use a simple loop like this:

```
for($i=1;$i<=date('n');$i++)
{
    echo date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $i, 0, 0);
}
```

For reference, `date('F')` outputs the full name of the month like August.

Edit: The `mktime()` function is tied to the user timezone, You are likely getting the wrong months because you aren't on the 0:00 timezone (like myself). As you are only after the months, this is an easy fix:

```
<?php
    for($i=date('n');$i>0;$i--)
    {
        echo date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, ($i), 2, date('Y')))."<br>";
    }
?>
```

I have also modified the for loop so that it works in reverse.

Comment: I think `for($i=1;$i<=date('n');$i++)` is better!

Comment: @Death Yes, you are right, writing a loop using `<` is pretty much muscle memory these days :P +1 for the well spotted though!

Comment: Thanks, but this list out December January Feburary March April May June July, I need to output all previous months of THIS year including the current month

Answer (score 0):

PHP's `date()` is perfect for this.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

```
$month = date('n'); // Get month, 1-12
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
 $month=date('m');

foreach(range(12,1) as $i)
{
  if($i<=$month):    
  echo date('F',mktime(0,0,0,$i));
  echo '<br>';
  endif;
}?>
```