# Display succeeding month php

Tags: php

I am a bit new to PHP
is there a way to display a month in succession?

the sample is my first date is `July 01, 2018`

the output should be

```
July 01, 2018
Aug 01, 2018
Sept 01, 2018 ..
```

and so on until to the date I declare

Update:
here is my code

```
$propd = "SELECT * FROM tbl_sample WHERE Person_ID = ".$Person_ID;
$prop_counter = $conn->query($propd);

while($pcount_Row = $prop_counter->fetch_assoc()) {
    $Acceptance_Date = $pcount_Row["Accpt_Date"];
}

/////////////////////////////

$NAcceptance_Date = strtotime($Acceptance_Date);
$nMonth = strtotime($Acceptance_Date);
$Start_Date = date('M d,Y', $NAcceptance_Date);

$x=1;
$Month_Counter=1;
$Monthly[$x] = $Start_Date;
//echo $Monthly[$x];
$x++;

$JDate=strtotime("June 01, 2018");
$JuneDate = date("M d,Y", $JDate);


while ($Start_Date != $JuneDate)
{
$Start_Date = date("M d, Y", strtotime("+1 month", $nMonth));
$nMonth= strtotime($Start_Date);
echo $Start_Date . "-" . $JuneDate . "<br>";
}
```

where

```
$Acceptance_Date = July 01, 2009
$JuneDate = June 01, 2018
```

but my won't stop at June 01, 2018

Comment: put your code which you have tried.

Comment: @GufranHasan i don't have one, don't know how to code it

Comment: At least an attempt?

Comment: Loop and http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get a list of months that have passed upto todays date - PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12071635/get-a-list-of-months-that-have-passed-upto-todays-date-php)

Comment: 1/ Create a var with your first date, 2/ Create a loop with a end condition (date max?), 3/ Each time you loop : display the current date then add one month untill end condition is false

Comment: You can use this answer and simply change the month counts within the for loop. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10829455/4034148

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Displaying the list of months using mktime for the year 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10829424/displaying-the-list-of-months-using-mktime-for-the-year-2012)

Answer (score 0):

Something similar to this should work for you, though you'll need to look up `strtotime()`, `date()` and `for` loops:

```
$time = strtotime("July 01, 2018");

$nextMonth = date("m d, Y", strtotime("+1 month", $time)); //Loop this til you find the date you want to stop at
```

But then you need to loop through until the date you want, then `break` out of the loop.

This is not a complete copy and paste answer, it requires you to do some work on it.

Comment: This does not answer to the question. You just get the next month not the list of the next months

Comment: You need to loop through as stated. It's not a full answer, it's an answer that makes you do some work yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
/* On met la date au format mysql. Enfoiré d'anglophones. LE SYSTEME METRIQUE ET NOS NORMES VAINCRONS */
    function date_to_mysql($album_date){
        $album_date = explode("-",$album_date);
        $date = intval($album_date[0]).'-'.intval($album_date[1]).'-'.intval($album_date[2]); /** add +1 to middle for month+1, in my case it's alreay formated */
        unset($album_date);
        return $date;
    }
?>
```

here's a way to do that in PHP
Wanna know the amout of months that passed?

Substract total by current month.

Want the month/day_name? PHP does it for you with date functions too or make an associative array and swap values

Comment: You can get the current month using date('m'), and you can loop starting from intval of day/year/month to max amout of month/day/year